# Socket programming

Tags: sockets

Is it possible to change the port of the server to which it is listening, when client sends a message to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close your socket, then open a new one on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible.
You can do it by simply terminating the socket on that port and starting a new one on any different port.